# Rails: Rename a Binary File uploaded to API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've seen a lot of threads that open up a file from a directory and rename it. But in my case, the user is uploading a file to a POST endpoint. I'd like to rename that file before uploading to my blob storage.

Here's what I have so far:

```
def picture
   @file = params[:file]
   @new_file_name = generate__filename()

   #this line didn't work
   File.rename(@file, @new_file_name + File.extname(@file))

   # begin upload here
end
```

I'm testing this by selecting the form-data value as file in Postman. How do I rename this file?

Comment: You need to write the file first.

Comment: Storing the data in the params to a File object? @JoshBrody is there an example I can refer to?

Comment: can you update and post the backtrace errors in your question?

Comment: `File.write` is your friend here.